# No module named 'exceptions' when importing cql or cqlsh in Python

Tags: python, cassandra, anaconda, cql

I'm running Python on Anaconda. I want to connect to cassandra using python but this is the error I am getting.

```
macs-MacBook-Air:~ mac$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cql/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cql.apivalues import *
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cql/apivalues.py", line 17, in <module>
    import exceptions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
>>>
```

**Edit:**

The import works on Python 2 as pointed out in the comments.

```
macs-MacBook-Air:~ mac$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:47:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cql
>>> con = cql.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 9023, 'keyspace', cql_version='3.4.2')
No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.transport.TSocket"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/connection.py", line 143, in connect
    consistency_level=consistency_level, transport=transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/connection.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/thrifteries.py", line 151, in establish_connection
    self.transport.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 269, in open
    return self.__trans.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 113, in open
    raise TTransportException(TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, msg)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to any of [('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 9023)]
>>>
```

Does this sound like a permission issue? Cassandra is hosted on an EC2 instance on AWS. Maybe, it is a permissions issue? Any suggestions.

Comment: `import exceptions` is only available in Python 2. It looks like the `cpl` package is Python 2 only. Try to run in Python 2 or see if there is a new version for Python 3.

Comment: This driver supports both 2.7 & 3.4 (may err with 3.6) - https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

Comment: What is your goal here? `cql` is outdated and deprecated. If you're starting a new project, I would recommend starting with the Datastax Python driver for Apache Cassandra (linked above by Ashish).
Your title mentions cqlsh, but your description does not. Is there something more about cqlsh?